# Download file in Zip

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

**i want to download file in zip,but i got error my code and regarding error are bellow**

**My code:**

```
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {

            zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
            zip.AddDirectoryByName("Files");
            //foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            //{
            //    if ((row.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox).Checked)
            //    {
            //        string filePath = (row.FindControl("lblFilePath") as Label).Text;
            //        zip.AddFile(filePath, "Files");
            //    }
            //}
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"~\Election\Latur"));
            var files = directory.GetFiles().ToList();                
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                zip.AddFile(file.ToString(),"Files");
            }
            Response.Clear();
            Response.BufferOutput = false;
            string zipName = String.Format("Zip_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.End();
        }
```

**when am using above code for download file in zip then follwing error occure**

**error**

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the error is happening on the line `zip.AddFile(file.ToString(),"Files");`?

Comment: no bro, error occure in  zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);

Comment: thanks Adrinan, your Second solution is currect,i.e file.ToString() is not contain full path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
         string folderpath = Server.MapPath(@"~\Election\Latur\");
        zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
        zip.AddDirectoryByName("Files");

        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"~\Election\Latur"));
        var files = directory.GetFiles().ToList();                
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
           var filepath = folderpath + file.ToString();
           zip.AddFile(filepath,"Files");

        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        string zipName = String.Format("Zip_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
        zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible cause of this error:

1- The directory "Files" not possible create(denied permission)
2- Not possible obtain files into "~\Election\Latur"

Anyway the lines:
            var files = directory.GetFiles().ToList();
            foreach (var file in files)

The type var i think is not correct for this. String with base64 coder is more correct.

Comment: `var` is fine - it just means Visual Studio works out the type for you.